# Can H2 database exist outside of the IDE - or does the data have to be manually inserted each time?

Tags: database, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, h2

I understand that H2 is an in-memory database.
I was watching videos from a (somewhat older) course on Mockito which uses the H2 DB for illustration.
In the videos I saw the H2 sql statement traces to create the table, and insert rows running by in their Eclipse IDE console.
However, I do not find any traces like it in my IntelliJ IDE.
Is there a setting to auto-insert data?

Or does the data have to be manually inserted each time.

Furthermore, when they are running JUnits on their repository, they do not seem to be running the SpringBoot server.
I am puzzled - does the DB exist outside of the IDE?

I [read up more on the features](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) and tried to change the url to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/Documents/Projects/regular-encourager/encourage/src/main/resources/data.sql'
```

But I get error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Me/Documents/Projects/regular-encourager/encourage/target/classes/data.sql]: CREATE TYPE Category AS ENUM('WhoIAmInChrist','Default'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Domain "CATEGORY" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TYPE Category AS ENUM('WhoIAmInChrist','Default') [90119-214]
```

When I comment out the CREATE Enum statements then I get error that it is an unknown type.

```
CREATE TYPE Category AS ENUM('WhoIAmInChrist','Default');
CREATE TYPE Tone AS ENUM('Default', 'Uplifting', 'Urging', 'Warning', 'Soothing', 'Comforting', 'Inspiring', 'Centering', 'Balanced');
CREATE TYPE Topic AS ENUM('Default', 'AcceptedInChrist', 'SignificantInChrist', 'SecureInChrist', 'NoAnxietyInChrist');
```

data.sql is:

```
drop table ENCOURAGEMENT if exists;
CREATE TYPE Category AS ENUM('WhoIAmInChrist','Default');
CREATE TYPE Tone AS ENUM('Default', 'Uplifting', 'Urging', 'Warning', 'Soothing', 'Comforting', 'Inspiring', 'Centering', 'Balanced');
CREATE TYPE Topic AS ENUM('Default', 'AcceptedInChrist', 'SignificantInChrist', 'SecureInChrist', 'NoAnxietyInChrist');
CREATE TABLE Encouragement(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, CATEGORY Category, TOPIC Topic, TONE Tone, MESSAGE VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(-1, 'Default', 'Default', 'Default', 'We walk by Faith, not by Sight');
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(0,'WhoIAmInChrist','AcceptedInChrist','Uplifting','John 1:12 I am God''s child.');
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(1,'WhoIAmInChrist','AcceptedInChrist','Uplifting','John 15:15 As a disciple, I am a friend of Jesus Christ.');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

| H2 mode | Connected apps | Persistent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| In-Memory | 1 | ❌ |
| File-persistent | 1 | ✅ |
| Server-mode | multiple | ✅ |

H2 can work in multiples modes: in memory, file persistent, and server. See [H2 Cheat Sheet](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html):

- The [**in-memory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database) option does not have any persistence and all data is lost once the database stops.
- The **file-persistent** option is still a single-user database but the data is saved on disk. Subsequent connections will see changes from previous connections.
- The [**server mode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_server) (client-server) is a separate process suitable for multi-user, multi-connections. This mode works more or less in the same way as a traditional database.

Finally, it's also possible to provide a SQL script to be run when starting H2, so tables and data is already there when your app starts.

Comment: Thanks. I read up more on the features and tried to change the url to `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~./data.sql'`

Comment: ...continued I get error: Please see question with details as error is too long to fit here

Comment: @likejudo What I've seen several times is that even though H2 is working as an in-memory database the data.sql script is run multiple times because of the connection pooling enabled automatically by Spring/Hikari. The workaround is quite simple: make sure you drop all tables, types, and other database objects at the begining of the script. You are already doing it with for one table using: `drop table ENCOURAGEMENT if exists;`. Just do it also for the type "Category".

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question - I made the change to drop the enums but no improvement.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75048587/398348

Comment: I realized the inserts are not happening but I do not know why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75115642/why-arent-rows-being-inserted-into-the-h2-db-from-my-script-even-though-the-dro