# Why aren't rows being inserted into the H2 Db from my script even though the drop table and create table is happening?

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, junit, h2

Why aren't rows being inserted into the H2 Db from my script even though the drop table and create table is happening?

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists encouragement CASCADE 
Hibernate: create table encouragement (id bigint not null, category varchar(255), message varchar(255), tone varchar(255), topic varchar(255), primary key (id))
2023-01-13 18:39:08.297  INFO 18108 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

No Inserts after this!

**Details:**

I am testing my SpringBoot application which uses the H2 db.
It is running in IntelliJ IDE.

When I launch the SpringBoot application in the IDE, I can query the console `http://localhost:8080/h2-console` in the browser. When I stop the IDE, I am unable to.
The DB url in `application.properties` is `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test`.

My other JUnit tests are working (mocked repository).

When I test the repository,
I run the SpringBoot application so that the DB is present,
but I get a zero length list back.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
class EncouragementRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    EncouragementRepository repository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    public void find_all() {
        List<Encouragement> list = repository.findAll();
        assertEquals(33,list.size());
    }

}
```

I don't know why it is failing and returning zero length list.

So I thought perhaps the DB isn't seeded.

I changed the db url to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/Documents/Projects/regular-encourager/encourage/src/test/resources/data.sql'
```

In `src/test/resources/data.sql` I included a script like this:

```
drop table ENCOURAGEMENT if exists;
drop TYPE Category if exists;
drop TYPE Tone if exists;
drop TYPE Topic if exists;
CREATE TYPE Category AS ENUM('WhoIAmInChrist','Default');
CREATE TYPE Tone AS ENUM('Default', 'Uplifting', 'Urging', 'Warning', 'Soothing', 'Comforting', 'Inspiring', 'Centering', 'Balanced');
CREATE TYPE Topic AS ENUM('Default', 'AcceptedInChrist', 'SignificantInChrist', 'SecureInChrist', 'NoAnxietyInChrist');
CREATE TABLE Encouragement(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, CATEGORY Category, TOPIC Topic, TONE Tone, MESSAGE VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(-1, 'Default', 'Default', 'Default', 'We walk by Faith, not by Sight');
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(0,'WhoIAmInChrist','AcceptedInChrist','Uplifting','John 1:12 I am God''s child.');
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(1,'WhoIAmInChrist','AcceptedInChrist','Uplifting','John 15:15 As a disciple, I am a friend of Jesus Christ.');
    
.....
```

Here is the IDE console:

loads jars here and then...

```
com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest
18:39:05.330 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
18:39:05.341 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
18:39:05.388 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper]
18:39:05.409 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest]: class path resource [com/dropaflame/encourage/data/EncouragementRepositoryTest-context.xml] does not exist
18:39:05.410 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest]: class path resource [com/dropaflame/encourage/data/EncouragementRepositoryTestContext.groovy] does not exist
18:39:05.410 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:39:05.411 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest]: EncouragementRepositoryTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:39:05.487 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest]
18:39:05.586 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Users\Me\Documents\Projects\regular-encourager\encourage\target\classes\com\dropaflame\encourage\EncourageApplication.class]
18:39:05.599 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.dropaflame.encourage.EncourageApplication for test class com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest
18:39:05.605 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest]: using defaults.
18:39:05.606 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
18:39:05.631 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@64e7619d, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@495ee280, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@4fa1c212, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@6ea2bc93, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3116c353, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@f627d13, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@4e928fbf, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@352ff4da, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@3224a577, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@2e32ccc5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@748741cb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@3e44f2a5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@295cf707, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@1130520d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@5f77d0f9]
18:39:05.637 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@20d7d6fb testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4ef782af testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.dropaflame.encourage.EncourageApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@11d8ae8b key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@130c12b7, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5d534f5d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6340e5f0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@6c1a5b54, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@9e45b0fa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@543295b0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
18:39:05.660 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@20d7d6fb testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest@59d4cd39, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4ef782af testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.dropaflame.encourage.EncourageApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@11d8ae8b key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@130c12b7, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5d534f5d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6340e5f0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@6c1a5b54, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@9e45b0fa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@543295b0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]].

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

2023-01-13 18:39:06.184  INFO 18108 --- [           main] c.d.e.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest   : Starting EncouragementRepositoryTest using Java 17.0.4.1 on Me-LAPTOP with PID 18108 (started by me in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Projects\regular-encourager\encourage)
2023-01-13 18:39:06.186  INFO 18108 --- [           main] c.d.e.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-13 18:39:06.538  INFO 18108 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-13 18:39:06.587  INFO 18108 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 40 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-13 18:39:06.701  INFO 18108 --- [           main] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
2023-01-13 18:39:06.964  INFO 18108 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:6f3c6875-d9bc-4c2c-b11f-3c25021050d9;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2023-01-13 18:39:07.347  INFO 18108 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-01-13 18:39:07.412  INFO 18108 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
2023-01-13 18:39:07.600  INFO 18108 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-01-13 18:39:07.690  INFO 18108 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

    Hibernate: drop table if exists encouragement CASCADE 
    Hibernate: create table encouragement (id bigint not null, category 

varchar(255), message varchar(255), tone varchar(255), topic varchar(255), primary key (id))
2023-01-13 18:39:08.297  INFO 18108 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-01-13 18:39:08.304  INFO 18108 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-13 18:39:08.775  INFO 18108 --- [           main] c.d.e.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest   : Started EncouragementRepositoryTest in 3.055 seconds (JVM running for 4.262)
2023-01-13 18:39:08.818  INFO 18108 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@20d7d6fb testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest@59d4cd39, testMethod = find_all@EncouragementRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4ef782af testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.dropaflame.encourage.EncourageApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@11d8ae8b key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@130c12b7, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5d534f5d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6340e5f0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@6c1a5b54, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@9e45b0fa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@543295b0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@50f05307]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: select encouragem0_.id as id1_0_, encouragem0_.category as category2_0_, encouragem0_.message as message3_0_, encouragem0_.tone as tone4_0_, encouragem0_.topic as topic5_0_ from encouragement encouragem0_
2023-01-13 18:39:09.244  INFO 18108 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@20d7d6fb testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.dropaflame.encourage.data.EncouragementRepositoryTest@59d4cd39, testMethod = find_all@EncouragementRepositoryTest, testException = org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <33> but was: <0>, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4ef782af testClass = EncouragementRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.dropaflame.encourage.EncourageApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@11d8ae8b key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@130c12b7, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5d534f5d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6340e5f0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@6c1a5b54, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@9e45b0fa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@543295b0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]

**org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :33
Actual   :0**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing together concepts from different testing domains.

The purpose of `@DataJpaTest` annotation is to delegate all "infrastructure magic" to `spring-boot`:

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and roll back at the end of each test. **They also use an embedded in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured DataSource). The @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation can be used to override these settings.**

You may actually observe that `@DataJpaTest` replaces database configuration - your logs contain the following:

```
Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:6f3c6875-d9bc-4c2c-b11f-3c25021050d9;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

The options are:

- disable that replacement via marking test class with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` or setting `spring.test.database.replace=none` in application properties
- [learn how bootstrap embedded database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html)

Comment: Excellent, it worked! Just a question - I do not see any traces in the console to drop the table, insert rows. Is there a setting to get it back?

Comment: @likejudo you obviously get another setup, another logs, etc... nobody can definitely say what is going on in your env without extra information and knowing your expectations.

Answer (score -1):

H2 database is just dummy database, it is just used for practice purpose, when you stop the server, I mean when your spring boot application stops, all the data dissappears, and you can't access even the H2 database then

Comment: "just used for practice" But  even for practice it should have inserted the rows