# How to embed H2 database to my own application to make it run on another computers

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I completed H2 database with few tables and I want to embed it to my application written in Intellij Community Edition. I tried to do this in two different ways but none of that works the way I want to.
First way with URL jdbc:h2:~/database but user home is different on every computer... The database works only on my pc.
Second way with URL jdbc:h2:./src/database and the database is inside the project indeed, connection works, but the tables appears to be empty even though while running H2 database engine (entering h2/bin/h2-version.jar) the tables contain data.
Why the database seems to be empty?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String URL = "jdbc:h2:./src/database";
    final String USER = "sa";
    final String PASSWORD = "";
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected to H2!");  
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from table1");
        while (resultset.next())
            System.out.println(resultset.getString(1));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

and Ive got an exception:
Connected to H2!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TABLE1" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
select * from table1 [42104-212]
at mainH2.main(mainH2.java:22)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TABLE1" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
select * from table1 [42104-212]

Comment: H2 can operate in different modes. It seems you want the second one in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977517/can-h2-database-exist-outside-of-the-ide-or-does-the-data-have-to-be-manually/74977996#74977996): single-user, persistent. How are you packaging your app? If it's a Maven/Spring app then it the URL can be relative to the location of the deployed JAR file. As simple as that. You'll need to detect if a new installation has an empty database, and if so, then run the 'CREATE` script to populate it the first time.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I dont use Spring/Maven, just pure Intellij Community Version. I put h2-(version).jar into project structure and it connects fine but database appears empty. I filled the database outside Intellij before putting into project structure.

Comment: The key aspect of my question is how are you packaging and distributing your app. As a single jar? Something else?

Comment: Generally I want to make the project portable. Im creating .exe file: so I make a single jar (artifact -> jar from modules with dependencies) Hope thats what you mean, if not give me please more details, I'm a simple beginner